# Empty executables after creating bind mount

Tags: filesystems, mount, chroot, executable, jails

I've created a bind mount in `/tmp/test` which I then use to establish a chroot jail. For example:

`mount --bind -o ro /usr/bin/ /tmp/test`

`chroot /tmp/test /some_executable`

This seems to work fine - most of the executables within that folder are accessible and I can interact with them normally from within the jail. However, there are at least a few files within the mount that show up as empty executables. Specifically, a class of nvidia executables used for interacting with a GPU device attached to my system:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         0 Feb 13 15:16 nvidia-cuda-mps-control*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         0 Feb 13 15:16 nvidia-cuda-mps-server*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         0 Feb 13 15:16 nvidia-debugdump*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         0 Feb 13 15:16 nvidia-persistenced*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         0 Feb 13 15:16 nvidia-smi*
```

If I try to mount one of those files directly, everything works as normal:

`touch /tmp/test/nvidia-smi && mount --bind -o ro /usr/bin/nvidia-smi /tmp/test/nvidia-smi`

```
ll /tmp/test/nvidia-smi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 678392 Jul 13  2021 /tmp/test/nvidia-smi*
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

**Edit**: This is what the nvidia files look like on the filesystem before the mount:

```
/tmp# ls -l /usr/bin/nvidia-*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  45824 Jul 13  2021 /usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14488 Jul 13  2021 /usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-server
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 252720 Jul 13  2021 /usr/bin/nvidia-debugdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  61976 Jul 13  2021 /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 678392 Jul 13  2021 /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
```

Filesystem information:

```
df -T

Filesystem      Type    1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay         overlay  31444972 14551624  16893348  47% /
tmpfs           tmpfs       65536        0     65536   0% /dev
tmpfs           tmpfs    16176692        0  16176692   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           tmpfs    16176692        4  16176688   1% /etc/config
/dev/nvme0n1p1  xfs      31444972 14551624  16893348  47% /etc/hosts
shm             tmpfs       65536        0     65536   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           tmpfs    16176692       12  16176680   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - edited the original question to include that.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Oh! It's an overlay filesystem. Maybe those don't `chroot`? (This is a docker container, isn't it? That's usually really important information.)